# IIS 7.5 Reverse Proxy Implementation

Tags: iis, url-rewriting

I am curious to understand how IIS 7.5 Reverse Proxy is implemented in Rewrite Module (v2).

I am planning to setup a website that will handle proxing between requests coming from users (internet) and my HTTP services that are deployed on the same server. I have setup a website within IIS and configured the reverse proxy logic. I've then setup another website on the same server and deployed all my WCF REST services there. I am planning to implement IIS offloading, common tasks (such as authentication, etc) on the reverse proxy website before the request gets to the actual services (like WCF routing service for SOAP). Configuration is working perfectly fine.

However I am trying to understand the implications of this setup. When IIS does reverse proxing, does it create a new HTTP request (and a new TCP port) between those two websites? And even if both sites are on the same server? Should I expect number of TCP connections opened on this server to get doubled when reverse proxy is used?

Furthermore, has anyone experienced any performance/resource issues with a similar setup?

Cheers,
OS